# ESLint is giving warning - Parsing error: Identifier expected in Qwik

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, qwik, qwikjs

Getting the following warning in my vscode editor from eslint

```
Parsing error: Identifier expected.eslint
(property) bind: value: Signal<string>
```

[image]

I can understand the typescript yelling at me due to some type mismatch, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Here is a trim down version of my code -

```
export default component$(() => {
    const action = useCreateUserAccount();
    const nameSig = useSignal(defaultValues.name);
    const emailSig = useSignal(defaultValues.email);
    const passwordSig = useSignal(defaultValues.password);

    useTask$(({ track }) => {
        const status = track(() => action.value?.status);
        if (status) {
            nameSig.value = defaultValues.name;
            emailSig.value = defaultValues.email;
            passwordSig.value = defaultValues.password;
        }
    });


    return (
        <>            
            <Form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action={action} >
                <div>
                    <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" bind: value={nameSig} placeholder="Write your name" />
                </div>
            </Form>
        </>
    );
});
```

**Deb dependencies using regarding Typescript & ESLint.**

- "@types/eslint": "8.37.0",
- "@types/node": "^20.1.4",
- "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.5",
- "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.5",
- "eslint": "8.40.0",
- "eslint-plugin-qwik": "~1.2.0",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the API is `bind:value` (without space) here is the [docs](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/components/rendering/#bind-attribute)

In VSCode, `Typescript and Javascript Language Features` linter mess up `bind:value` and many other attributes because it adds spaces. Please use [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) to lint your code because it works better.

Comment: Regarding typescript & eslint, I'm using the following deb dependencies in my project. Which one I should remove?

"@types/eslint": "8.37.0",
"@types/node": "^20.1.4",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.5",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.5",
"eslint": "8.40.0",
"eslint-plugin-qwik": "~1.2.0",

Comment: I checked these dependencies and all of them are in the official starter so I use to leave them as is. I have Prettier as default VSCode formatter.